# Eclipse - custom launch configuration - apply/revert buttons

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm making my custom launch configuration type. I implemented the launch configuration tab and faced the strange problem. When I do the following

```
private void update() {
    setDirty(true);
    updateLaunchConfigurationDialog();
}
```

in one place of my launch configuration tab class, it works fine and Apply button becomes enabled. But when I do it in another place, it doesn't work. I found something similar at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/164755/ , but it didn't help me to solve this problem.

See the code fragments below.

```
    addButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSelectionToTableViewer(tree.getViewer().getTree().getSelection());
            table.refresh();
            update(); // Apply button is enabled
        }

        private void moveSelectionToTableViewer(TreeItem[] selection) {
            // ...
        }
    });

    removeButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            int[] selectionIndices = table.getTable().getSelectionIndices();
            table.getTable().remove(selectionIndices);
            tree.getViewer().refresh();
            update(); // Apply button is NOT enabled!
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Another question that may clarify things. If you do "Add" (which enables the Apply) and then you do "Remove" does that disable the Apply button?

Comment: As a sidenote: replace MouseListener with SelectionAdapter.

Comment: Apply button remains enabled after add and remove. Yes, I will replace it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your problem from this information alone, But just a few things to check:

1. Have you verified that `setDirty(true)` is being called (e.g. with println or breakpoint?)
2. Have you put a watch on `org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.fDirty` to see if it changes back?
3. Are you overriding `isDirty`?
4. Is removing the an item from the table causing the launch configuration to become invalid in some way, i.e. you can't `Apply` when invalid values are in the launch config. For example, to be saveable, `canSave` must return `true` for all the tabs that are part of the launch configuration.

This is (one of the) place(s) that sets the enabled state of the Apply button:

`org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.updateButtons()`

```
/**
 * updates the button states
 */
private void updateButtons() {
    boolean dirty = isDirty() && canSave();
    fApplyButton.setEnabled(dirty);
    fRevertButton.setEnabled(dirty);
}
```

5. Consider if a mouse listener is what you want. Note that you are responding to MouseDown, that may not do what you expect if a person tabs over to the control and presses Enter/Space instead. The more typical thing to do would be an `addSelectionListener` for a button. (Could it even be that responding to the event at this unusual time is causing the problem?)

Comment: 1. Yes, look at the update() method, setDirty(true) certainly being called
2. Nice idea, I will check it in few hours and report here, thanks
3. No
4. I don't think so. Could you please clarify what could be invalid in launch configuration?

Comment: Updated 4 with more info. BTW As for 1 I can see that update() calls setDirty(), but what I can't tell is if you actually made sure that when you do the mouse down that you are in fact calling the method, and that there is not something else going wrong (hidden exception in the refersh, for e.g.). Sorry if I am being very basic for 1, no offence if you have verified this, I just want the best possible answer.

Comment: Added a 5th option, although I recommend you make that change regardless :-)

Comment: I overrided canSave() for all tabs, now it just returns true. Also I checked `isDirty()` and `canSave()` before and after calling `updateLaunchConfigurationDialog();`. It returns true always. Also I repalced `MouseListener` on `removeButton` with `SelectionListener` and overrided `widgetSelected()` method. I checked that `update()` method is called when user clicks the `removeButton`. But unfortunately it didn't fix the problem, Apply and Revert buttons are still disabled after clicling `removeButton`. Is there any options left? I think I'm going crazy with that problem :(

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.updateButtons when you click the Remove? Is the breakpoint hit? If not, try stepping through from your update() until you get to the problem. If you solve it, please post the answer and accept it :-)

Comment: I tried it and realized that `boolean isDirty = isDirty();` is `false` in `updateButtons()` method! I think that's the reason of my problem. Thank you very much for advices, now I know where to look at least :) I realized that the problem is in `isDirty` method. At the last line of it `!fOriginal.contentsEqual(workingCopy)` should be `true`, but seems like it's `false`. I will check it now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94345/discussion-between-another-programmer-and-jonah-graham).